# Как решить баг с импортом SVG в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Импортирую разные картинки но отображает одну первую вставленую svg. Все остальные наследуются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
import { ReactComponent as Arms} from '../../assets/svg/armsIcon.svg'
import { ReactComponent as House } from '../../assets/svg/house.svg'
import { ReactComponent as Car } from '../../assets/svg/car.svg'


 <Arms className={category === 'saleBuy' ? 'boardAdsBar__icon boardAdsBar__icon--active' : 'boardAdsBar__icon'}/>
  <House className={category === 'property' ? 'boardAdsBar__icon boardAdsBar__icon--active' : 'boardAdsBar__icon'}/>
```

Если импортирую одну картинку, то всё нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может код у svg иконок одинаковый?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов нет, картинки разные

Comment: Можно решить проблему только посмотрев на код. Сможете сделать песочницу в codesandbox?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-clarke-78uvl?file=/src/App.js . Тут не работает вообще.ReactComponent работатет только когда создаешь проект с помощью create-react-app

Comment: Попросите дизайнера дать вам нормальные svg файлы.Тут проблема в svg файлах

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Если я импортирую один свг, то все нормально отображает. Я думаю дело не в файле

Comment: Было бы не плохо если бы побольше кода было, и в каком месте используется импорт иконок ?

Comment: @dresser Окей,завтра добавлю. Я просто думаю что я как-то не правильно импортирую